# Does android system receives the broadcast which is send from our application?

Tags: android, android-intent

I am new in android and need some help. I want to know that when we use `sendBroadcast(Intent intent)` method we can receive through `onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)` method in our application. 
What i want to know is that instead of our application, android system can receive this broadcast or not?

Is it possible that android operating system receives an intent broadcast, which is sent from our application?

Comment: send intent from one activity to other related acitivity

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the broadcast means some the broadcast already used by system like phone call, sms etc. for our custom broadcast can system handle it we must handle itself we can handle system broadcast but system can't handle it